# Where can I ask the question about HPC cluster for scientific purpose configuration and setup?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For professional server configuration, there is a community named [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

However, almost every posts on there are about the server on business purpose.

I am wondering where can I post my question about cluster for academic, research and scientific purpose?

Comment: There is computerscience.se but they don't seem to take those kind of questions: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and on [TCS.se](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) they have a list of sites to try.

Comment: So your question would be the right configuration for each purpose?

Comment: Still serverfault does have plenty of those questons: https://serverfault.com/search?q=hpc